# ExtUtils::MakeMaker how to install configuration file

Tags: perl

I'm using ExtUtils::MakeMaker to distribute my perl module, which is composed of a PM file and an executable.

The executable have to load a configuration file.

I want my Makefile.PL to :

- generate the configuration file ;
- install it in the correct PREFIX ;
- modify the executable to set the real path of the configuration file.

But I have no idea of how to do this.

Comment: Make your code fall back to a sensible default behavior if it runs without a configuration file.  The tool might well die if information it needs is not passed in one way or another, but requiring it to be specifically in a file sounds nasty.

Comment: The configuration file store only user/group for a setuid/setgid, by default the program will set it to nobody:nobody. Anyway, the program have to load the configuration file, and I don't know how to set the real path (PREFIX/etc/...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where Makemaker is a real pain. You have to know how to do this in `make`.

First, *Makefile.PL* is just a Perl program, so you can do anything you want with that.

Second, you can use a *.PL* file as a program that runs to generate the real file. For instance, you could have a *lib/Module.pm.PL*. At build time, the system runs that program and uses the output to create *blib/lib/Module.pm*. See the documentation for `PL_FILES`.

Third, you can add tasks to the `make` targets so your processing happens at the right time. Double colon targets add to the tasks already defined.

```
 all ::
      perl create_config.pl > config.pl
      install ... config.pl
```

To add this to *Makefile* from *Makefile.PL*, you have to add special subroutines to the `MY` namespace. It's all documented in Makemaker, but the docs assume you are comfortable with `make`.

But, all of that is really a pain in the ass even if you know how to do it. You think you have it figured out, then someone has a different setup or a different sort of `make`. You spend all your time with fiddly bits to make it compatible everywhere. This is one of the major reasons the Perl gods invented [Module::Build](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aBuild). It's much easier to add custom processing and modify build targets, *and* you get to do it all in Perl! The rule of thumb is that if you don't know how to do it with Makemaker, it's time to use [Module::Build](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aBuild).

Comment: I'm using Module::Build, thanks to you. It's much more easier. I'm now able to install the default configuration file in the correct directory. But I can't figure out how to set the real path of my configuration file in my executable. Doing the modification directly in the Build.PL ? Or I have to define a PL_files ?

Comment: I solved the problem : In Build.PL I create an INI file named 'config' (that's not a problem because my module needs Config::IniFiles), and in a file (setted in PL_files), I get values from that INI file and generate the script correctly